# Why admob ads not showing?

Tags: android, admob

When I put test ads in my app it works fine and showing but when I change them to my ads, I get this message "No ad config"

Do I should publish my app on store first to show ads or what because it showing when I use test ads.

Comment: I have the same problem, and my app is in production in Google Play.